# heroku node app doesnt start - $ heroku opens gives access denied error

Tags: node.js, heroku, hosting

I am pretty new to heroku but i managed to follow all the steps in their getting started document https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app.

But i get stuck after $ heroku open.
It opens a prompt saying class not registered  and get access denied error on the console.

```
C:\Windows\System32\node-js-getting-started>heroku create
Creating quiet-retreat-4698... done, stack is cedar-14
https://quiet-retreat-4698.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/quiet-retreat
-4698.git
Git remote heroku added

C:\Windows\System32\node-js-getting-started>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 375, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (295/295), done.
Writing objects: 100% (375/375), 208.74 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 375 (delta 50), reused 375 (delta 50)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote:        Node engine:         0.10.x
remote:        Npm engine:          unspecified
remote:        Start mechanism:     Procfile
remote:        node_modules source: package.json
remote:        node_modules cached: false
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        Resolving node version 0.10.x via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 0.10.35...
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        No cache available
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        express@4.9.8 node_modules/express
remote:        ├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
remote:        ├── utils-merge@1.0.0
remote:        ├── fresh@0.2.4
remote:        ├── cookie@0.1.2
remote:        ├── escape-html@1.0.1
remote:        ├── range-parser@1.0.2
remote:        ├── cookie-signature@1.0.5
remote:        ├── finalhandler@0.2.0
remote:        ├── vary@1.0.0
remote:        ├── media-typer@0.3.0
remote:        ├── methods@1.1.0
remote:        ├── parseurl@1.3.0
remote:        ├── serve-static@1.6.4
remote:        ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3
remote:        ├── depd@0.4.5
remote:        ├── qs@2.2.4
remote:        ├── on-finished@2.1.1 (ee-first@1.1.0)
remote:        ├── debug@2.0.0 (ms@0.6.2)
remote:        ├── proxy-addr@1.0.5 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@0.1.6)
remote:        ├── etag@1.4.0 (crc@3.0.0)
remote:        ├── send@0.9.3 (destroy@1.0.3, ms@0.6.2, mime@1.2.11, on-finished
@2.1.0)
remote:        ├── type-is@1.5.5 (mime-types@2.0.7)
remote:        └── accepts@1.1.4 (negotiator@0.4.9, mime-types@2.0.7)
remote:
remote: -----> Checking startup method
remote:        Found Procfile
remote:
remote: -----> Finalizing build
remote:        Creating runtime environment
remote:        Exporting binary paths
remote:        Cleaning npm artifacts
remote:        Cleaning previous cache
remote:        Caching results for future builds
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:
remote:        node-js-getting-started@0.1.2 /tmp/build_408ad10f6b6641451cf54af5
8aaaf01d
remote:        └── express@4.9.8
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 5.7MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v3
remote:        https://quiet-retreat-4698.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.

Warning: Your console font probably doesn't support Unicode. If you experience s
trange characters in the output, consider switching to a TrueType font such as L
ucida Console!
To https://git.heroku.com/quiet-retreat-4698.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master

C:\Windows\System32\node-js-getting-started>heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:1X.

C:\Windows\System32\node-js-getting-started>heroku open
Opening quiet-retreat-4698... Access is denied.
done
```

Comment: Not sure why you would get `Access is denied` like that, but it seems to be working: http://quiet-retreat-4698.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Okay just figured it out. It worked When I used the cmd with ruby.

Comment: http://quiet-retreat-4698.herokuapp.com/ this just started running, it wast up before